# ColumnMapping.Add alternative

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell

I have my PowerShell script:

```
$dataSource = "HPVIE1APARBLD21";                                       
$database = "tempdb"                                                   

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;  #setting connection
$connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$dataSource;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True;";
$connection.Open();

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$command.Connection = $connection;

$as = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$as.SelectCommand = $command;
$filename = 'C:\XML\apc.xml';            #file to be loaded into sql server database table

$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$ds.ReadXml($filename);    #reading from the file -- line gives output InferSchema

$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
$dt=$ds.Tables[0];

$bcp = New-Object "Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy" $connection; #bulkcopy to the destination table.
$bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tempor";

$bcp.ColumnMappings.Count;
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Clear();

$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("StartTime","StartTime");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("EndTime","EndTime");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("Status","Status");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("ProcessedTime","ProcessedTime");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("ScheduleId","ScheduleId");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("Model","Model");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("ModelVersion","ModelVersion");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("ModelVersionState","ModelVersionState");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("ModifiedTime","ModifiedTime");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("WriteBackLastRunTime","WriteBackLastRunTime");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("ModifiedBy","ModifiedBy");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("ModelType","ModelType");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("IsTimeRange","IsTimeRange");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("WriteBackStatus","WriteBackStatus");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("RetryWriteBack","RetryWriteBack");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("NumOfRetry","NumOfRetry");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("FrequencyUnits","FrequencyUnits");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("ScheduleType","ScheduleType");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("CustomType","CustomType");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("WritebackProcessedTime","WritebackProcessedTime");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("DiagStatus","DiagStatus");
$bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID","AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID");

$bcp.ColumnMappings.Count;

if ($connection.State -ne [Data.ConnectionState]::Open) {

    "Connection to DB is not open."

    Exit

}

$bcp.WriteToServer("$dt");        #writing to server  -- not loading content of xml file to sql server table
$connection.Close();
```

Now for this script, my output is: [image]
I want to insert the values of the following xml file: apc.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> 
<NewDataSet>
   <Table>
        <StartTime>2017-01-14T18:30:00+05:30</StartTime>
        <EndTime>2017-01-15T18:30:00+05:30</EndTime>
        <Status>1</Status>
        <ProcessedTime>2017-04-06T05:51:18.843+05:30</ProcessedTime>
        <ScheduleId>db6f3178-4702-456c-904b-2cd833b54efa</ScheduleId>
        <Model>Gasco_Hotfix</Model>
        <ModelVersion>G3</ModelVersion>
        <ModelVersionState>1</ModelVersionState>
        <ModifiedTime>2017-04-06T05:51:58.48+05:30</ModifiedTime>
        <ModifiedBy>l4-dc\ilbinstall</ModifiedBy>
        <ModelType>1</ModelType>
        <IsTimeRange>true</IsTimeRange>
        <RetryWriteBack>false</RetryWriteBack>
        <NumOfRetry>0</NumOfRetry>
        <FrequencyUnits>2</FrequencyUnits>
        <ScheduleType>1</ScheduleType>
        <CustomType>0</CustomType>
        <DiagStatus>2</DiagStatus>
        <AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID>9544940d-8d1a-e711-80d3-0050569c2fb6</AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID>
 </Table>
   <Table>
        <StartTime>2017-01-15T18:30:00+05:30</StartTime>
        <EndTime>2017-01-16T18:30:00+05:30</EndTime>
        <Status>1</Status>
        <ProcessedTime>2017-04-06T05:51:18.843+05:30</ProcessedTime>
        <ScheduleId>db6f3178-4702-456c-904b-2cd833b54efa</ScheduleId>
        <Model>Gasco_Hotfix</Model>
        <ModelVersion>G3</ModelVersion>
        <ModelVersionState>1</ModelVersionState>
        <ModifiedTime>2017-04-06T05:52:29.073+05:30</ModifiedTime>
        <ModifiedBy>l4-dc\ilbinstall</ModifiedBy>
        <ModelType>1</ModelType>
        <IsTimeRange>true</IsTimeRange>
        <RetryWriteBack>false</RetryWriteBack>
        <NumOfRetry>0</NumOfRetry>
        <FrequencyUnits>2</FrequencyUnits>
        <ScheduleType>1</ScheduleType>
        <CustomType>0</CustomType>
        <DiagStatus>2</DiagStatus>
        <AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID>9644940d-8d1a-e711-80d3-0050569c2fb6</AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID>
 </Table>
 </NewDataSet>
```

Into the table dbo.tempor in the database tempdb.

Could anyone help me up with the error?
And also, i would like to know if there is a method to not add column mappings manually by writing each column names. I mean, is there a way to dynamically add columns without having to manually type up each column name?

The purpose is sometimes in future i would have to add more columns to the original table, then again i can't come back to the script and do changes manually. So if there is an alternative method please do help me up with it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that this appraoch cannot get the XMLs schema automatically. I'd try an approach like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> 
<NewDataSet>
   <Table>
        <StartTime>2017-01-14T18:30:00+05:30</StartTime>
        <EndTime>2017-01-15T18:30:00+05:30</EndTime>
        <Status>1</Status>
        <ProcessedTime>2017-04-06T05:51:18.843+05:30</ProcessedTime>
        <ScheduleId>db6f3178-4702-456c-904b-2cd833b54efa</ScheduleId>
        <Model>Gasco_Hotfix</Model>
        <ModelVersion>G3</ModelVersion>
        <ModelVersionState>1</ModelVersionState>
        <ModifiedTime>2017-04-06T05:51:58.48+05:30</ModifiedTime>
        <ModifiedBy>l4-dc\ilbinstall</ModifiedBy>
        <ModelType>1</ModelType>
        <IsTimeRange>true</IsTimeRange>
        <RetryWriteBack>false</RetryWriteBack>
        <NumOfRetry>0</NumOfRetry>
        <FrequencyUnits>2</FrequencyUnits>
        <ScheduleType>1</ScheduleType>
        <CustomType>0</CustomType>
        <DiagStatus>2</DiagStatus>
        <AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID>9544940d-8d1a-e711-80d3-0050569c2fb6</AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID>
 </Table>
   <Table>
        <StartTime>2017-01-15T18:30:00+05:30</StartTime>
        <EndTime>2017-01-16T18:30:00+05:30</EndTime>
        <Status>1</Status>
        <ProcessedTime>2017-04-06T05:51:18.843+05:30</ProcessedTime>
        <ScheduleId>db6f3178-4702-456c-904b-2cd833b54efa</ScheduleId>
        <Model>Gasco_Hotfix</Model>
        <ModelVersion>G3</ModelVersion>
        <ModelVersionState>1</ModelVersionState>
        <ModifiedTime>2017-04-06T05:52:29.073+05:30</ModifiedTime>
        <ModifiedBy>l4-dc\ilbinstall</ModifiedBy>
        <ModelType>1</ModelType>
        <IsTimeRange>true</IsTimeRange>
        <RetryWriteBack>false</RetryWriteBack>
        <NumOfRetry>0</NumOfRetry>
        <FrequencyUnits>2</FrequencyUnits>
        <ScheduleType>1</ScheduleType>
        <CustomType>0</CustomType>
        <DiagStatus>2</DiagStatus>
        <AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID>9644940d-8d1a-e711-80d3-0050569c2fb6</AccountingPeriodCase_PK_ID>
 </Table>
 </NewDataSet>';
```

--The query will read all columns and insert this to the target table

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.tempor(StartTime,EndTime,[Status],ProcessedTime /*more columns*/)
 SELECT t.value(N'(StartTime/text())[1]',N'datetime') AS StartTime
       ,t.value(N'(EndTime/text())[1]',N'datetime') AS EndTime
       ,t.value(N'(Status/text())[1]',N'int') AS [Status]
       ,t.value(N'(ProcessedTime/text())[1]',N'datetime') AS ProcessedTime
       --and so on
 FROM @xml.nodes(N'/NewDataSet/Table') AS A(t);
```

### Some explanation

To test this, you can copy my script (together with the XML declaration) into a new SSMS query window and execute it. `.nodes()` returns all (repeated) `<Table>` nodes as derived table.

Using SQL-Server's native XML support allows for fast and typesafe queries. Your XML looks clean and neat, so this should be rather easy.

If this is possible for you, I'd create a *stored procedure* accepting the XML as input (either `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `XML`). You can call this from PS as a *one-liner*.

If you expect issues (wrong/missing data) it is recommended to use a tolerant *staging* table, use this for validation, cleansing, and do the final import from there.

> The purpose is sometimes in future i would have to add more columns to
>   the original table, then again i can't come back to the script and do
>   changes manually.

When you come back to add more columns to the table, it is easy to add them to the SP too...